# How to sync to store instance in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mobx, mobx-react

I have a store in react that contains an @observable names categories = [];
Now  i want to import this store into 3 other stores but i want to sync `categories` in two of them. like if `categories` change in one store it applies to the other store as well. whats the best way to do it?

I add a sample of what i want, but its just a protptype so please dont mind the syntax problem, i'm trying to understand the proper way to sync properties between stores.

```
export default class CategoricalStore {
   @observable categories =[];

   @computed get categories () {
      let categories = toJS(this.getCategories());
   }

   @action.bound addCategories (item, e) {
      this.categories.push(item);
   }
}

import CategoricalStore from './CategoricalStore';
export default class store1 {
   this.categories= new CategoricalStore()
}


import CategoricalStore from './CategoricalStore';
export default class store2 {

    this.categories= new CategoricalStore()
}

import CategoricalStore from './CategoricalStore';
export default class store3 {

   this.categories= new CategoricalStore()
}
```

In the above example i want to sync store1 and store2 `categories`.

Comment: Why not just use Redux?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin why use redux. its just an alternative state management. doesn't fix the architectural design issue here.

Comment: @JoelHarkes, Redux is observables and stores. Exactly what is trying to be done above.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach this problem.

My solution is also expandable to all future properties of each store.
 Store 1 and Store 2 share a category list and Store 3 has an individual list.

```
import { observable, action, computed } from "mobx";
```

Create 3 stores as required with references to a Root Store

```
class Store1 {
  constructor(instance) {
    this.categories = instance.sharedCategories;
  }
}

class Store2 {
  constructor(instance) {
    this.categories = instance.sharedCategories;
  }
}

class Store3 {
  constructor(instance) {
    this.categories = instance.singleCategories;  }
}
```

Create category store that houses the categories array.

```
class CategoricalStore {
  @observable categories = [];

  @action.bound
  addCategory(data) {
    this.categories.push(data);
  }
}
```

Root Store which holds both lists of categories and all 3 stores.

```
class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.sharedCategories = new CategoricalStore();
    this.singleCategories = new CategoricalStore();
    this.store1 = new Store1(this);
    this.store2 = new Store2(this);
    this.store3 = new Store3(this);
  }
}
export default RootStore;
```

`RootStore.sharedCategories.addCategory(any)` is how to update both stores.

I also went ahead and provided an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7mxlrz067x) written within React.

Answer (score 1):

You've updated the answer, now I've understood what you want to do. Probably I'll do something like this:

**Store1.js**

```
import { observable, computed } from 'mobx';

class Categories {
    @observable categories = [];
    @computed get listCategories(){
        return this.categories;
    }
}
const CategoriesStore = new Categories();
export { Categories, CategoriesStore };
```

**Store2.js**

```
import { CategoriesStore } from './Store1';

class Store2 {
    categories = CategoriesStore.listCategories;
}
```

**Store3.js**

```
import { CategoriesStore } from './Store1';

class Store3 {
    categories = CategoriesStore.listCategories;
}
```

With the following code, you'll import an existing instance from mobx, exported from `Store1` and if you want, you can create a new instance by `let newStore = new Categories();`.

** **OLD ANSWER BEFORE USER EDIT** **

If `categories` is already a observable, then you don't need to worry about this.

You should create a `@computed` property get values from `categories`.

```
...
import { computed } from 'mobx';
...
@computed get getCategories(){
    return this.categories;
}
```

Comment: i updated the question, could you please take a look?

Comment: no store2 can not extend from store1, they are doing completely diffrent things , they are just using one same component that is CategoricalStore.

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi read his example thoroughly he doesn't extend anything either. seems to be exactly the answer to the question you pose.

Comment: @Lucas thanks but no, still not the thing i need. in both your answers you synced all the instance of categories, but as i said in myquestion, it must only be synced in two stores not all of them. if we have store1, store2 and store3, the categories are synced in store1and store2 but has no influence on store3

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lucas but maybe i can make the example simpler.

You dont just wanna share the categories, you want to share the **CategoriesStore** so there is only a single source of truth and all changes reflect to the same store:

```
export default class CategoricalStore {
   @observable categories = [];

   @computed get categories() {
      let categories = toJS(this.getCategories());
   }

   @action.bound addCategories (item, e) {
      this.categories.push(item);
   }
}
```

and in your store implementation file (if you want to split it over multiple files use, @lucas's example.

```
import CategoricalStore from './CategoricalStore';
// here you just create the store once and only once!
var categoryStore = new CategoricalStore();
export default class store1 {
   this.categories = categoryStore;
}

export class store2 {
    this.categories = categoryStore;  //and we just share the same istance.
}

export class store3 {
   this.categories = new CategoricalStore();
}
```

## another solution - forward properties properties

Here would be an example of my code solution, this way you only need 2 code classes for 2 stores. You could make an interface and let all three of them implement that so you can use them interchangeable.

```
export class StoreInnerShared {
  constructor(rootStore){
     this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }
  getCategories(){
     return this.rootStore.categories;
  } 

   //alternative getter property:
   get categories() {
      return this.rootStore.categories;
   }
}

export class StoreIndependent {
  @observable categories = [];
  getCategories(){
     return this.categories;
  } 
}

new rootStore = new StoreIndependent();
new seperateStore2 = new StoreIndependent();
new innerSharedStore = new StoreInnerShared(rootStore);
```

Comment: thanks but as i said in my question, categoryStore must only be synced in store1 and store2 , store3 has its own category that cant be sync with others

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi than just create a new store instance for that one, see i updated my example.